# Scroll table row into view (and to top) even if it is the last row

Tags: javascript, scroll, html-table

I have a table with dynamic content.

When it loads I want a certain row (it differs which one) to be at the top.
This is doable in cases where the table has enough rows below the one I want to scroll into view.

But when I want for instance the 12th row at the top and the table only has 14 rows. It will not scroll down far enough because there is nothing to fill up the remaining space.

I'm guessing I need something to fill the left over space. But something that should shrink to 0 if the table is in a scrollposition that it already fills its container.
I could get an element to fill up that space. But when the user scrolls up it should reduce in height (as the table contents move down) and not grow after that. Meaning the user can scroll up to the top just once.

Someone asked: "Did you try to write something yourself?"

Well, I've come up with this. It almost works on page load, then when you navigate from that to a different anchor, the spacer becomes way too large. For some reason much larger than on the first page load.

Scrollreference is the element that the table scrolls within.

```
var createSpacer = function (row, height) {
    // add element with height equal to distance
    spacer = document.createElement('div');
    var container = getClosestBySelector(row, tableContainerSelector);
    container.appendChild(spacer);
    spacer.className = spacerClass;
    spacer.style.height = height + 'px';
    return spacer;
};

var getInitialSpacerHeight = function (row) {
    var scrollreference = getClosestBySelector(row, scrollReferenceSelector);
    // get scrollreference that has this row
    // return distance from top of table
    var sizeAboveRow = row.getBoundingClientRect().top - scrollreference.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.scrollY;
    return sizeAboveRow;
};

var navigationHandler = function (e) {
    // set anchored row to top even if table doesn't have enough rows to put it there
    var rowID = e.detail.newLocation.substring(e.detail.newLocation.indexOf("#") + 1);
    // only if the new location has an anchor
    if (rowID !== "") {
        var row = document.querySelector('#' + rowID);
        var spacerHeight = getInitialSpacerHeight(row);
        if (spacerHeight === 0) {
            // if spacer height = 0 we don't need to act
            // remove listener and/or spacer here?
            return;
        } else {
            createSpacer(row, spacerHeight);
            var scrollreference = getClosestBySelector(row, scrollReferenceSelector);
            scrollreference.scrollTop = scrollreference.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself?

Comment: You said that "there is nothing to fill up the remaining space", and you are correct there, so basically you should think on "how would I make that space?"

Comment: Perhaps a better way to say it would be not just something that takes the remaining space but: something that sizes to the amount I need to be able to put that one row at the top. And I think that's where it gets complicated fast: how do you know what height to set for that element and how to fluently reduce it to 0 as the user scrolls up.